# Xamarin - is there a way to notify Xamarin.Forms from a native project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So, I have this code in my native project (Android MainActivity OnCreate), which doesn't do anything:

```
var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
TinyMessengerHub tmh = (TinyMessengerHub)container.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();

tmh.Subscribe<LocalMessage>((m) => {
    // this doesn't show
    Toast.MakeText(this, m.Content, ToastLength.Long);
});
```

Here's where I notify the app using TinyMessenger:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        string msg = data.GetString("message");

        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
        TinyMessengerHub tmh = (TinyMessengerHub)container.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();
        tmh.Publish(new LocalMessage(this, msg));
    }
}
```

I tried to add TinyMessenger to my PCL, but apparently it was not supported (there were missing references in the TinyIoc.cs file etc., the same code runs well in the Android project)

So, is there any way to inform Xamarin.Forms about an arriving message so that I could e.g. display an alert window?

Comment: Xamarin Forms has a built in [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/) component which might do what you need.

Comment: Do you have any kind of an example? The examples online seem to deal with messaging within shared code, but how would I implement this between projects?

Comment: This: https://thomasbandt.com/a-nicer-messaging-interface-for-xamarinforms will work cross all borders, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example is done with a `Page`, but you can subscribe/unsubscribe with your `Application` class, or selectively within your app logic.

In your `Xamarin.Forms` project subscribe/unsubscribe to a message via `MessageCenter`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "ShowAlertMessage", (sender, msg) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            MainPage.DisplayAlert("Push message", msg, "OK"); 
        });
    });
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object>(this, "ShowAlertMessage");
}
```

In "native" project send message via `MessageCenter`:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string> (this, "ShowAlertMessage", "StackOverFlow Rocks");
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to run the DisplayAlert function in the UI thread, like this:
`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { 
    MainPage.DisplayAlert("Push message", msg, "OK"); 
});`

Comment: @UrticaDioica, you are correct, I updated the answer with the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: it's not working for me, I get the next exception:


System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
@SushiHangover

Comment: @DamirBeylkhanov Without an context, I would have not idea, post a new question with your problem

Comment: @SushiHangover I have absolutely the same context as described in this question

and exception is occured when I send message

p.s. XF v.2.3.4