# Xamarin how to open xamarin forms page from android project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-toolbar

I want to open Xamarin forms page from Xamarin Android project. On android project I created toolabar item image, where I am calling event to open page from Xamarin forms project.

Here is my MainActivity.cs toolabar image item implementation:

```
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
      private IMenu CurrentMenu { get; set; }
      private ImageView imgSmallC { get; set; }

      public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
            {
               ActionBar.DisplayOptions = ActionBarDisplayOptions.HomeAsUp | ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom | ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowTitle | ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowHome;  
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ActionBar.ThemedContext.GetSystemService(LayoutInflaterService);
                View customActionBarView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.actionbar_custom_view_done, null);  

                imgSmallC = (ImageView)customActionBarView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgSmallC);

                imgSmallC.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof(MyPopupPage));
                };
                return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
}
```

In StartActivity I am calling MyPopupPage.xaml page from Xamarin forms project, but unfortunately when I am debugging project and I click on toolbar image I get such a error:

> System.ArgumentException: type Parameter name: Type is not derived
>   from a java type.

Comment: Could you please share what solution you came up with? My question is kinda similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508566/cannot-open-a-xamarin-forms-page-from-xamarin-android

Answer (score 4):

You can not use a `Xamarin.Form` based `Page` as an Android `Activity`, they are two completely different *things*.

You can access the `Xamarin.Forms` `Application` singleton from the `Xamarin.Android` project and use that to `PushModelAsync` or `PushAsync`

#### Example (using full Namespace):

```
    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PushPageFromNative.MyPage());
```

#### A `Dependency Service`-based Example:

**Interface:**

```
using System;
namespace PushPageFromNative
{
    public interface IShowForm
    {
        void PushPage();
    }
}
```

**`Xamarin.Form`-based code:**

```
var pushFormBtn = new Button
{
    Text = "Push Form",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
};
pushFormBtn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
        DependencyService.Get<IShowForm>().PushPage();
};
```

**`Xamarin.Android` Dependancy Implementation:**

```
async public void PushPage()
{
    // Do some Android specific things... and then push a new Forms' Page
    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PushPageFromNative.MyPage());
}
```

Comment: I want to open a Xamarin Froms Page from android Activity not on any button click. So where should write your "Xamarin.Forms-Based Code" should be place ?

Comment: It works, Thanks. One more concern is that it is opening without navigation bar, So can a content page open with a navigation bar ?

Comment: Nice. Anything similar for a single element (e.g. text label) on a Forms View?

Comment: @GGleGrand Not sure what you mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, your answer here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621140/xamarin-is-there-a-way-to-notify-xamarin-forms-from-a-native-project ) did the trick.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508566/cannot-open-a-xamarin-forms-page-from-xamarin-android . I tried your solution but for me the value of Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current was null. So then I tried to initialize it and the other values (MainPage, Navigation), but still the Forms Page does not display in the foreground with that code. I tried to RunOnUiThread as well but the view doesn't change. I also tried to play around with the MainActivity inheriting from FormsApplicationActivity & FormsAppCompatActivity with no success