# Pop or Dismiss a Xamarin.Form ContentPage after pushing from Native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin, Shared Project.

Is there any way to dismiss or pop a ContentPage after launching it from an iOS or Android Native stack?

I currently do this to launch the ContentPage:

iOS

`viewController.PresentViewController(contentPage.CreateViewController(), true, null);`

Android

`StartActivity(typeof(ContentPageActivity));`

and I get the page to come up on both platforms, although I cannot dismiss the Page.

Things that don't work:

`popasync(), popmodalasync(), removepage()`

Maybe I have to create a reference to their parent view that launched them?  But I was under the impression on Android, each ContentPage needs a single Activity to launch.  And on iOS you need to launch it from a view controller and create the view controller content page.

Any insights to this would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: `Xamarin.Form`'s `Page` != Activity (or ViewController), if you need to launch a `Page` class from your "native" project, Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(....)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967324/xamarin-how-to-open-xamarin-forms-page-from-android-project/38968591#38968591

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover.  Yes I just want to launch a content page from our native screens in a shared project.  I'll test it out.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @SushiHangover unfortunately your solution does not work.  Lets say I want to push to a new ContentPage via an Activity.  Even using await that line didn't work.  It compiles, but when the push is called, nothing happens.

Comment: Also, Im using `namespace AppName.Droid` and `namespace AppName.iOS`