# Open Xamarin.Forms Page from Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am receiving Firebase Pushnotifications in Xamarin.Android.
While receving I want to open a specific content page of my Xamarin.Forms App.

I use

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ShowAlert(null));
```

"ShowAlert" is the page I want to open.

The constructor of "ShowAlert" is beeing called an executed, but the page is not beeing opened. What's missing?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Are you initializing Xamarin Forms `Forms.Init(this, bundle);`

Comment: Yes I do. In "onCreate" of MainActivity (Xamarin.Andoid).

Comment: Is the push notification coming in while your app is already running?  I'm wondering if the main activity isn't being run for a push notification delivered when the app isn't running.

Comment: Yes, App is running and in foreground.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968591/8093394), it should work. Please, post the context where that line of code is being called. Maybe something else is invalidating the call like a thread issue.

Comment: Are you calling PushAsync from the UI thread?  [Device.BeginInvokeOnUIThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/) ...

Comment: "Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread" was the solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great!  I've added it as an answer to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling PushAsync from the UI thread? [Device.BeginInvokeOnUIThread .](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/)