# Cannot open a Xamarin.Forms "Page" from Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**Context:** Our team is trying to use `Xamarin.Forms` (XF) [Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms) to slowly convert our project from using `Xamarin.Native` to XF, for easier maintenance & implementation of features in the future.

**The Problem:** As you can see in the function parameters on the lines referenced by the links, Xamarin allows you to convert any type of XF `Page` to a native `ViewController` in [iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/PageExtensions.cs#L75), but it only allows converting a XF `ContentPage` to a native `Fragment` in [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/PageExtensions.cs#L8).

**Importance:** This difference plays a major role, because through `Xamarin.Native Android`, you can't implement a XF `NavigationPage`. What does that mean? From within Xamarin.Native Android, you can't convert your app to use XF, so you can't call functions like `PushAsync` or `PopAsync`.

**Added Explanation:** There are different types of "Page" objects-like ContentPage, NavigationPage, and so on. You can open NavigationPages on [iOS, as you can see in this sample here](https://github.com/saamerm/XamarinFormsInsideXamarinNative/blob/4e50edfb2cf38ecb31e505bb0e1a98d9bab614b1/BlankNativeApp/iOS/ViewController.cs#L24) which allows using functions like `PushAsync` or `PopAsync`, by simply doing:

```
UIViewController user2 = new NavigationPage(new TestPage()).CreateViewController();
```

So for [Android as seen here](https://github.com/saamerm/XamarinFormsInsideXamarinNative/blob/4e50edfb2cf38ecb31e505bb0e1a98d9bab614b1/BlankNativeApp/Droid/FormsNavigationActivity.cs#L27), currently we can only do this

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = new TestPage().CreateSupportFragment(this);
```

and I was wondering is there a way to do something like this?

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = new NavigationPage(new TestPage()).CreateSupportFragment(this);
```

**Question:** Has anyone opened a `Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage` from Xamarin.Android native before? Does anyone know of a workaround that will allow us to use the PushAsync and PopAsync functions?

*PS: Here's the [Github](https://github.com/saamerm/XamarinFormsInsideXamarinNative) playground which was a Spike*

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you trying to get Xamarin form page reference in the native android renderer? Instead of pasting link to whole github you might want to add the concerned code here ( I was able to open a Page in an Activity instead of a fragment, )

Comment: @Prateek thank you for your comment, didn't realize the lack of clarity. I made edits with more explanation as you requested.

Comment: @Saamer,If you want to open xamarin.form page from xamarin.android, I suggest you can see the same thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967324/xamarin-how-to-open-xamarin-forms-page-from-android-project.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I tried out what SushiHangover said, but that proposed solution throws a null reference exception. I left a comment there too.

Comment: @Saamer If you look at the NavigationPage code (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs) there is no way, that I currently see, to convert a Forms' NavigationPage to an Android Fragment as it is constructed at the top level Activity context. Maybe someone else knows more.

Comment: I think @SushiHangover is right. `NavigationPage` is converted to [`INavigationPageController`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8e4fb9bccdb35db31e444f0e679f57feacae7c3f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs#L82) and in the renderer you can get handle of the pages(fragments) inside it . I would think of it as `FragmentManger` rather than a `Fragment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the API currently stands, it is not possible to implement.

I did create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8153), so if you could go there and give it a few thumbs up to create a possible way, that would be great